# Firebase - Get child of a child with no key name

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Tried every answer around. Thing is I do not know much Javascript.

I want to access the child of a child. **Name** and **Email**.
But they are under 
Name > unique ID > Name & Address

The code I'm trying is:

```
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child("users");

rootRef.on("child_added", snap =>{

    var name = snap.child("name").val();
    var email = snap.child("email").val();

    console.log(name, email);

});
```

And I get printed out:

```
null  null
```

[image]

I suppose I'm one level short, but I dont't know how to go in deeper in the structure.

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using the user's name as a key? You should  use a unique ID for your keys, and then your code would work as expected.

Comment: It's an app a thrd party developer made for me. I'm doing a simple back-end to retrieve some data. So can't really change the data structure because it is being used in production already

Comment: I'm guessing then that the unique ID is not known when you make the query? Only the top level name?

Comment: Yes. I want to tap inside the uniqueID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Super weird that the Name is the key, and not the unique ID right underneath it. That being said, assuming each user has only one child like in your example, and that you don't know what the unique ID is, you can retrieve the ID by iterating the props of the JSON object, then retrieve the fields you want like so:

```
    firebaseApp.database().ref().child('users').once('child_added').then(function(snap) {
        console.log('child added');

        var json = snap.val();
        var key;
        for (var field in json) {
            key = field;
            break;
        }

        var name = json[key]["name"];
        var email = json[key]["email"];

        console.log(name, email);
    });
```

Comment: If you want to edit there was only missing a }); at the end of the code